# ansync unable to get the value in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I am trying to get the element be clicked after making certain decision. I have to loop through certain async loops and then I loose the variable. Not sure what can I do to get the value of elt.

Here is my code

```
 element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).each(function(elt, index) {

                    elt.getText().then(function(text) {

                        if(index==0 && text=='logout'){

                            elt.click();


                        }

                        if(index==0 && text == 'My Account'){

                            elt.click();

                        }

                    });
                });
```

so the elt.click gives me this error

```
  Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.2 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why cannot you just get the first menu element and click it? `element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).first().click()` Thanks.

Comment: I am just trying this was because I may need to put some more checks in

Comment: Okay. Could you please describe your test scenario a little bit more so we can get the context you are working in? Thanks!

Comment: Well on the site there could be a scenario when the <li> nay have logout or my account as its first element. If its logout, then I have to click on that element. If it is my account then I have to do something different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well on the site there could be a scenario when the `<li>` nay have logout or my account as its first element. If its logout, then I have to click on that element. If it is my account then I have to do something different

I would *get the text of the first menu item* and then decide what to do depending on it's value:

```
var firstMenuItem = element.all(by.css('.top-bar li')).first();
firstMenuItem.getText().then(function (text) {
    if (text === "Log Out") {
        firstMenuItem.click();  // logging out
    } elif (text === "My Account") {
        // do smth else
    } else {
        // probably fail the test here
    }
});
```